# How can I run a yarn app/How to run a yarn dev server?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, yarnpkg

I've always used just npm and never yarn/webpack explicitly. I need to run the code from this repo:
https://github.com/looker-open-source/custom_visualizations_v2

Like a dev server or something to ensure it's serving the files properly but I don't see a "run" like `npm run start`. Does this just not exist with yarn? It feels like this code should work as is and I shouldn't have to add anything.

EDIT: I've now tried `yarn run watch` but it just seems to build the code again and not actually host anywhere

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`npm run somecommand` just looks up in the `"scripts"` field of `package.json` for the key
`somecommand` and executes the value in the terminal.

So `npm run start` basically runs the `start` script from `package.json`
The same thing is done using `yarn` via simply `yarn start`

In the linked repo, there isn't a `start` script in the `package.json`, rather a `watch` script, so you should be able to run it with the below steps:

1. `yarn` to install dependencies after cloning the repo to local (similar to `npm install`)
2. `yarn watch` to start the webpack server (analogous to `npm run watch`)

---

**Edit:**
Turns out the `watch` command is just setting up webpack to watch for changes and recompile the project every time there is a change.

To run a development server, you will need to add another script preferably with name `start` and use `webpack-dev-server`

So the `package.json` has entries like:

```
...
    "watch": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --watch --progress",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js",
...
```

Then running `yarn start` should open a dev server at `localhost:8080`

Comment: And where does it run at? Which localhost port? Also thank you!

Comment: Should run at `localhost:8080` by default unless specified otherwise in `webpack.config.js`

Comment: Okay so when I run those commands it builds, tells me all the entrypoints, then tells me all the modules, but doesn't say anything else like where it's running. Viewing port 8080 refuses to connect. Also I'll always mark an answer as accepted when I've completely solved the pain point